# sftp return code

Tags: sftp

I seacrhed the site for this problem but could not  find solution.Problem is related to sftp.I am running a script which accepets 7 parameters,does SSH and uploads the file on sftp server.Parameters i supply are-server,user,port,source_directory,target_directory,source_file and tager_file.
if everything goes fine, file is uploaded without any error and return code is 0.
Problem is if any parameter is wrong, like target_directory, even then script returns 0 as return value.Here is how script looks-

```
   typeset targetUsername=$1

typeset targetHostname=$2

typeset sftpPort=$3

typeset sourceDir=$4

typeset targetDir=$5

typeset sourceFilename=$6

typeset targetFilename=$7

typeset cmdPut="put ${sourceDir}/${sourceFilename} ${targetTempDir}/${tmpFileNam
e}"

typeset cmdRen="rename ${targetTempDir}/${tmpFileName} ${targetDir}/${targetFile
name}"

sftp ${sftpOption} ${targetUsername}@${targetHostname} <<EOF

${cmdPut}

${cmdRen}

bye
EOF

sftpStatus=$?
```

sftpStatus is supposed to return the status.But i am getting status as 0 always.
Any idea, how to resove this?
Thanks alot in advance.

Answer (score 8):

You need to run `sftp` in batch mode, by putting your commands in a file and passing that to `sftp`. You will then get an exit code of 1 if there is a failure and 0 for success.

Here is some sample code:

```
# create a temporary file containing sftp commands
BATCH_FILE="/tmp/$(basename $0).$$.tmp"
echo ${cmdPut} > ${BATCH_FILE}
echo ${cmdRen} >> ${BATCH_FILE}

# run sftp in batch mode
sftp -b ${BATCH_FILE} ${sftpOption} ${targetUsername}@${targetHostname} 
sftpStatus=$?

rm ${BATCH_FILE}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I will try soon and put the result here.

Comment: Hi,i m getting error in renaming the file."No such file or directory"

Comment: are you sure the targetDir exists?

Comment: oops.there was problem with directory.Its working fine now.thanks

Comment: Thank you, so much for this solution. It worked for me as well.